# Change Intent screen size

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the screen size when calling an `Intent`?

For example when I do

`Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

can I change the size of this `Intent`? Because it starts in fullscreen and I don't want it to be fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** possibility to start the `Intent` not in full size. This `Intent` starts the default `Android` camera `Activity`.

If you want it to be inside your App you have to build it by yourself or use a library:

- https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android
- https://github.com/natario1/CameraView
- https://github.com/fabian7593/MagicalCamera